# Facebook review rejected for using open graph photos

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am developing an app in iOS which uses facebook to login. User can access facebook photos within the application. When I submitted simulator build to review team, it got rejected with the following reason:

> Your Facebook login is not recognizing my test user but is rather presenting me with a preset user. Please make sure that your app can log me in and pull photos from my test user's albums before resubmitting.

Please help me to understand the above statement.

To get photos following code is used:

```
    if (![[FBSession activeSession] isOpen])
{
    [[FBSession activeSession] openWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {
        [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/me/photos"
                              completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                                  if (!error){
                                        /*Success*/
                                  }else
                                  {
                                      /*Handle Error*/;

                                  }
                              }];
    }];
}
```

Another question: Is there developers forum or any kind of developers support from Facebook?

Comment: Are you able to login with different diffedrent user with facebook login?

Comment: @vivek Yeah, I tried with few (application Test users)Test user account and login was successful.

Comment: Try your build in distribution mode and ask your friends to login for you in your app. There is some thing stuck in your application (may be in user defaults, if you're storing credentials there) your username or password. Thats why its appearing in front of review team. Otherwise, there is no possibility for appearing your login info there. Cheers.

Comment: After 3 days of blocking I submitted app again with one modification. I was saving Facebook login details to NSUserdefaults. Modified the key that it should not read from previous version, now reviewer verified the build and granted permissions.

Comment: hi @Raviprakash - are you there buddy ?

Comment: hi @Raviprakash .   Did you resolve this problem my friend?  Could you please tick any useful answer to help keep the board tidy. Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're just accidentally logging in, somehow, as a test user, (it could be due to a plist, some sort of NSUserDefault, or a number of reasons.  In this code ...

```
  if (![[FBSession activeSession] isOpen])
{
    [[FBSession activeSession] openWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {
        [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/me/photos"
          completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
              if (!error){
                    /*Success*/
              }else
              {
                  /*Handle Error*/;

              }
          }];
    }];
}
```

at "Success" just add a few lines of code like ..

```
NSString *emailCheck = [result objectForKey:@"email"];
if ( emailCheck == nil ) NSLog(@"emailCheck woe");
NSLog(@"emailCheck is %@", emailCheck);
```

and the same for

```
[result objectForKey:@"first_name"];
[result objectForKey:@"last_name"];
```

Be sure to build to distribution mode (AND test the other), try it a few times and see.

You'll quickly find the issue.

**A CRITICAL PROBLEM**:  it's extremely difficult to "logout" of Facebook on your actual device, your iPhone.

BEFOER TESTING just click to Facebook.com on your iPhone to triple-check WHO you are actually logged in as.

You should **DELETE the Facebook app** and "control panel Facebook setting" on your iPhone, and use only the "normal" login via web site -- to eliminate those variables.